# Azure Devpos: How to deploy a specific release manually?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a typical pipeline that automatically builds and deploys each night to QA.  Then every week or so, we take a particular build and deploy to beta.  The every two weeks, we take a particular build and push to production.

One issue I have, is that in order for me to push to beta or prod, I must cancel all releases since the last push to the environment.

Is there anyway to push a specific release, or a way to bulk cancel a number of releases?

Comment: *One issue I have, is that in order for me to push to beta or prod, I must cancel all releases since the last push to the environment.* - Why? You shouldn't have to do that. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Why?  Because Azure Devops will not allow me to deploy a release unless I cancel all prior releases. No error message, the deploy option is just not available.